# Getting text inside p which isn't inside another p

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have value inside div like this:

```
<p>
Example text I would like to scrape
<p>Example text I do not want to scrape</p>
</p>
```

How can I only return "Example text I would like to scrape"?

Comment: Does the text that you want *always* come before a nested paragraph? If so, it's a bit hacky, but you could do `.split('<p>')` on your text, and then grab the right index. 

The more flexible approach would be with a regex though.

Comment: @SimonR thanks a lot! I am trying it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the re module for regular expressions,
in case your scrape-text includes a specific pattern.
Here is a very basic pattern example with just plain text:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"Example text I would like to scrape")

html_elements = """<p>
Example text I would like to scrape
<p>Example text I do not want to scrape</p>
</p>
"""
print(re.sub(pattern, "", html_elements))
```

Comment: Actually, I guess that it's the opposite - the text I don't wanna scrap is constant. I get your point on how to solve this! Merci!

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """<p>
Example text I would like to scrape
<p>Example text I do not want to scrape</p>
</p>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')

print(soup.p.text)
```

Output will be:

```
Example text I would like to scrape
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do this with regex. We can match anything (`.*`) preceded by a `<p>` and a line break (`\n`), and followed by a line break and a `<p>` :

```
import re

pattern = re.compile("(?<=(<p>\n)).*(?=(\n<p>))")

html_elements = """<p>
Example text I would like to scrape
<p>Example text I do not want to scrape</p>
</p>"""

result = pattern.search(html_elements).group()
print(result)
```